Why do we use perturbation theory instead of statistical error?
In perturbation theory, the solution to a given quantum physical problem cannot be solved to an exact precission. But the approximate function which yields similar solutions can be improved by adding some "perturbing" terms into the approximation. For instance, an approximate term $A_0$ can be improved to match the exact solution $A$ by adding perturbative terms $A_1$, $A_2$, etc. with some parameter $\epsilon$:
$$
A = A_0 + \epsilon^1 A_1 + \epsilon^2 A_2 + \epsilon^3 A_3 + \cdots
$$
Given that $A \approx A_0$ even before we apply the perturbative series, why is it imperative that we find the other terms of $A_i$ and parameters $\epsilon^i$, so that $A$ has an exact solution? Why don't we accept the discrepancy as a statistical error as we often do in physical experiments?

The correction terms $A_1, A_2,\ldots$ are deterministic, so they are of a completely different nature than statistical errors.

Why would you "accept the discrepancy", when there are tools that explain the experimental results? Perturbation theory is extremely useful not only because it yields quantitatively correct values, but because it offers intuitive explanations to all sorts of physical phenomena.

You start with wave functions that are exact solutions to a ‘close’ problem, and now use those to get the solution to a more complex problem.

To add to what others have already correctly commented, a big difference fram random error is that the terms in a perturbation series are controlled, in that one orders the contributing terms from "major to minor". Think about the analogy of a Taylor series: adding more and more terms makes the approximation better, and you have a bound on the error from only including a finite number of terms.

Adding a weak magnetic field as in the Zeeman effect is hardly a discrepancy, and neither are transitions rates computed using perturbative methods.

If you are doing perturbation theory, odds are the statistical errors in your experiment are smaller than the perturbative corrections.
For example, consider the anomalous magnetic moment of the electron $g$, which is perhaps the best measurement we have so far. Wikipedia gives the experimental value for $g$ at
$$g_{\text{exp}} = 2.001\,159\,652\,180\,59(13).$$
Notice the ridiculously small uncertainty. How does this compare to theory? At tree-level (zeroth order in perturbation theory), the Dirac equation predicts
$$g_0 = 2.$$
This is clearly wrong in the accounts of the uncertainty of the experimental value. Considering $g_0$ to be correct would be similar to someone in Experimental Physics 101 measuring the acceleration of gravity on Earth at $5 \text{m}/\text{s}^2$ and finding it a good value. At one-loop (first order in perturbation theory), we get the corrected value
$$g_1 = g_0 + \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} \approx 2.001\,161\,4,$$
which is clearly much better, but still not good. $\alpha$ is the fine-structure constant, by the way. At fifth-order in perturbation theory (including terms up to $\alpha^5$), Wikipedia gives the value
$$g_{5} = 2.001\,159\,652\,181\,643(764),$$
which finally is compatible with the experimental value.
Perturbation theory is necessary because without it we get our predictions wrong. The level of precision nowadays is so big that the standard model fails to match experiment if you keep only the zeroth-order terms: it is only successful from first-order onward. The experimental stochastic errors are way smaller than the perturbative corrections.

I would add that most high-precision measurements are designed to measure exactly the correction terms in perturbation theory. Consider that the name of the best result for the muon's magnetic moment — which has the same leading-order terms $2+\alpha/2\pi$ as the electron, but which has different sensitivity to perturbations from high-energy physics — the name of the experiment is "gee minus two." The perturbations are the entire point of the measurement.
